# setOnClickListener don't do anything when i deny a permission - android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-permissions

I have my principal `activty`, first i call a dialog to warn to the user the 
permission, when the user click "Accept" in the GPS permission the `buttons` works fine, but when i "deny" the permission the `button` dont work

This is my class:

```
public class InicioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int count=0;
int tempInt = 0;


private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseUser;
private Button mButtonTrabajador;
private Button mButtonCliente;
private static final int RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM = 99;
private static final int RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERME = 122;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/RobotoLight.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );

    String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
    final int res = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    String permission2 = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
    final int res2 = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission2);

    mButtonCliente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIrARegistroCliente);
    mButtonTrabajador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIrARegistroTrabajador);



    mButtonCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && res2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Intent intent = new Intent(InicioActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
               //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{

                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Los permisos tienen que ser activados o no podra continuar, desea actualizarlos?");
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ir a configuracion", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", InicioActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });


    mButtonTrabajador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && res2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(InicioActivity.this, RegisterActivityWorkers.class);
                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{

                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Los permisos tienen que ser activados o no podra continuar, desea actualizarlos?");
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ir a configuracion", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", InicioActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    });



    RequestPermissions();
}



@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

private void RequestPermissions(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(InicioActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InicioActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(InicioActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InicioActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERME);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_LOCATION_CONTACTS_PERM: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {





            } else {


            }
            return;



        }
    }
}




}
```

The problem continues when i close the app and when i call a dialog in the onCreate i have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you should check the permissions again in the onClick?

Comment: @cricket_007 the permission are checked when i did the click and if i deny shows a Dialog, but don't work don't shows a dialog

Comment: Your `onCreate` is only called once and `checkCallingOrSelfPermission` are therefore loaded only then, not after you click deny

Comment: Also, you need to store `res` and `res2` from within `onRequestPermissionsResult` if you are trying to see if they are granted permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are not showing alertDialog. Please use `alertdialog.show()` for showing AlertDialog.
After then use below AlertDialog Code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
                // set title
                //alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure to Cancel the Subscription ?");
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Los permisos tienen que ser activados o no podra continuar, desea actualizarlos?");
                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        //.setMessage("After cancelling you will automatically got logout and then you have to buy subscription again")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ir a configuracion", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

when user deny the permission at first , then for second time you gotta use rational, here's a sample code to work with it

```
public void checkPermission() {

    Log.e(TAG, " inside checkSelfPermission()");


    resultCode = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    System.out.println(TAG + " resultCode at start :" + String.valueOf(resultCode));

    if (resultCode != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        //This block only will get executed after you denied first
        //Here you can show why You need , then try again
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "---You disabled previously, I have to show it again ----");


            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setCancelable(false).setTitle("Hi Dumb User")
                    .setMessage("You denied Permission ! before !! Which is required\n" +
                            "If you still deny ,then go to Setting ").
                    setPositiveButton("TRY AGAIN ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            //request Again

                            requestPermission();


                        }
                    }).setNeutralButton("DISMISS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                }
            }).show();

        } else {

            Log.w(TAG, " --else --");
            requestPermission();//ask 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are saying that your negative button or cancel button from dialog is not working then you can try this

```
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

and also I'm surprised where are you calling the dialog show.

```
alertDialog.show();
```